# Grab specific values from columns with disordered rows

Tags: r, ncbi

As the consequence of a misformatted file (which is unfortunately the only file available) I have a few thousand columns each with 9 rows of data in them. Unfortunately, the actual values are in a different order in each column.

I need to extract matched ***locus_tag=*** and ***gene=*** and/or ***product=*** values for each column whilst keeping the column order intact so that these do not get mismatched. Another complication is that these are formatted as  "gene=ltas" so I had thought some kind of grepl would be useful.

However, I also need them ordered so that each row only contains one either the correct value (e.g. gene=) or NA:

| `Column A` | `Column B` |
| --- | --- |
| `gene = ltas` | `NA` |
| `NA` | `product = hypothetical protein` |
| `locus_tag = RAS_R12345` | `locus_tag = RAS_R14053` |

Here is an example of the data that I am working with:

| `header 1` | `header 2` |
| --- | --- |
| `Parent=gene-SAS_RS00035` | `Name=hutH` |
| `gbkey=CDS` | `gene_biotype=protein_coding` |
| `inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:WP_002461649.1` | `locus_tag=SAS_RS00040` |
| `Dbxref=Genbank:WP_000449218.1` | `gbkey=Gene` |
| `locus_tag=SAS_RS00035` | `old_locus_tag=SAS0008` |
| `Name=WP_000449218.1` | `gene=hutH` |
| `cds-WP_000449218.1` | `gene-SAS_RS00040` |
| `protein_id=WP_000449218.1` |  |
| `product=NAD(P)H-hydrate dehydratase` |  |

I'n not sure where to start with coding this as it is so disordered and poorly formatted, so any advice would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
  dat <- structure(list(`header 1` = c("Parent=gene-SAS_RS00035", "gbkey=CDS", 
                                     "inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:WP_002461649.1", 
                                     "Dbxref=Genbank:WP_000449218.1", "locus_tag=SAS_RS00035", "Name=WP_000449218.1", 
                                     "cds-WP_000449218.1", "protein_id=WP_000449218.1", "product=NAD(P)H-hydrate dehydratase"
), `header 2` = c("Name=hutH", "gene_biotype=protein_coding", 
                  "locus_tag=SAS_RS00040", "gbkey=Gene", "old_locus_tag=SAS0008", 
                  "gene=hutH", "gene-SAS_RS00040", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                           9L), class = "data.frame")


prod <- apply(dat, 2, function(x){
  prod_ind <- grep("^product", x)
  if(length(prod_ind == 1)){
    out <- gsub("(product=.*)", "\\1", x[prod_ind])
  }else{
    out <- NA
  }
  out
})

gene <- apply(dat, 2, function(x){
  gene_ind <- grep("^gene=", x)
  if(length(gene_ind == 1)){
    out <- gsub("(gene=.*)", "\\1", x[gene_ind])
  }else{
    out <- NA
  }
  out
})

locus <- apply(dat, 2, function(x){
  locus_tag_ind <- grep("^locus_tag=", x)
  if(length(locus_tag_ind == 1)){
    out <- gsub("(locus_tag=.*)", "\\1", x[locus_tag_ind])
  }else{
    out <- NA
  }
  out
})

dplyr::bind_rows(gene, prod, locus)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   `header 1`                          `header 2`           
#>   <chr>                               <chr>                
#> 1 <NA>                                gene=hutH            
#> 2 product=NAD(P)H-hydrate dehydratase <NA>                 
#> 3 locus_tag=SAS_RS00035               locus_tag=SAS_RS00040
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The example above does this in three parts, each time searching for one of the things you're interested in.  Then, it combines all the results together.

Comment: That's done it. Thank you so much for your help!